# Acquire bearer token using http_request_post plugin in Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I would like to authenticate using the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Flow in an application context. It is my understanding that it is not possible to use the http_request_post plugin to send a request to the OAuth URI oauth2/token to retrieve a bearer token, for the following reason: The Content-Type attribute in the Content parameter for the plugin is hardcoded as "application/json" while the OAuth endpoint is expecting it to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". [Background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/exposed-apis-create-app-webapp?view=o365-worldwide#get-an-access-token)

Is my understanding correct and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this alternative approach. I try to reproduce same thing in my environment got this output using postman with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
POST 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxx-f3a0c218f3b0/oauth2/v2.0/token 
client_id:4KIxxxxxx2CS2UasSu9zTXhrMNQy6sQcKw
scope:https://management.azure.com/.default 
client_secret: xxxxxxxxxxxzTXhrMNQy6sQcKw 
grant_type:client_credentials
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Or**

**PowerShell with Bearer Token**

[image]